# How to use Element-wise Proofs?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Proof using element wise:

(A ∩ B ∩ C)’ = A’ ∪ B’ ∪ C’

I'm getting some issue proving this question.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us what you've tried and where the :"issue" is. Then perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By an "element wise" proof I assume you mean the most basic method in set proofs- by considering individual elements in the sets.  To prove "X= Y" for sets X and Y, prove both "X is a subset of Y" and "X is a subset of Y".  And to prove "X is a subset of Y you start "if x is in X" and use the properties of both X and Y to conclude "then x is in Y".

Here "X" is (A ∩ B ∩ C)'.  If x is in (A ∩ B ∩ C)’ then x is **not** in A ∩ B ∩ C.  That, in turn, means that x is **not** in at least one of A, B, or C.  So I would use "cases":
case 1: x is not in A. Then x is in A' so is in A' ∪ B' ∪ C'.
case 2: x is not in B. Then x is in B' so is in A' ∪ B' ∪ C'.
case 3: x is not in C. Then x is in C' so is in A' ∪ B' ∪ C'.
 That proves that (A ∩ B ∩ C)'is a subset of A' ∪ B' ∪ C'.

Now do that the other way.  If x is in A' ∪ B' ∪ C' then x is in at least one of A', B', C'.  Again do "cases":
case 1: x is in A', x is **not** in A so ...

Comment: Thank you for make me understanding "element-wise" proof, this was helpful.